# Duplicate Source Folder Structure in Eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm encountering an issue in my Eclipse project where I'm seeing two seemingly duplicated source folder structures. The project is a Spring Boot application, and I have noticed that I have two src/main/java folders and two src/test/java folders

[[image: The image:]

The packages from src/main/java have a package icon while the others from src→main→java have a folder, the classes are also different(in terms of icon),the same thing is with test

Comment: What do you have in the "Source" tab of the "Java Build Path" in the Project Properties?

Comment: There is no duplicated file structure. It's two views of the same thing: the Java view with source folders > packages > files > classes > fields, methods, nested classes, etc. and below the file structure view with only folders and files. Read the help for more details.